# Hive and Mahout Integration

Tags: hive, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have a situation in my project where I need to get the data from HIVE table, process this data to produce recommendations, and then again save these recommendations into the HIVE table.

This is the sample code for getting recommendations using Mahout.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("data/TestData.csv"));
    UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
    System.out.println("similarity"+similarity);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(5, similarity, model);
    System.out.println("neighborhood::"+neighborhood);
    UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
    System.out.println("recommender:"+recommender);
    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(2, 5);
    System.out.println("recommendations"+recommendations);
    for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
        System.out.println(recommendation);
    }
}
```

Now here instead of using the CSV file in the `DataModel` I want to use HIVE Tables and then save the recommendations again into the HIVE Table.

I have found some post about this but none of them served my purpose.

Sorry if I am being a nutshell but I am totally new to mahout and hive and trying to learn these technologies.